# Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(MovingDirection: any) => boolean'

Tags: angular

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(MovingDirection: any) => boolean'
```

All I want to do is use the result of my subscription as a boolean not an Observable.

canEnterStep2 only accepts boolean.

I need to somehow call it from inside canEnterStep2, and then based on output, return a boolean true or false.

But it doesnt seem to be working and I am stuck for ideas!

Is there a workaround?

```
  canEnterStep2: (MovingDirection) => boolean = () => {
    this.checkUsernameExists().subscribe(
      res => {
          if (res) {
              // do some stuff here
              return true
          } else {
              // do some stuff here
              return false
          }
      })
   }
```

```
  checkUsernameExists(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userService.getUserByUsername(this.username.toLowerCase().trim()).pipe(map(result => {
      if (result) {
        if ((result.length > 0) && (result[0]['username'] === this.username.toLowerCase().trim()) && (result[0]['uid'] !== this.user.uid)) {
          this.logger.debug('Username belongs to another user');
          return true;
        } else {
          this.logger.debug('Username does not belong to another user');
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        this.logger.debug('Username could not be determined');
        return false
      }
    }));
  }
```

Comment: can you show where are you using `canEnterStep2` method ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asynchronously check some conditions, you must go async all the way. Something like

```
canEnterStep2: (MovingDirection) => Observable <boolean> = () => {
   if (/* ...conditions... */) {
      return this.setUserPersonalDetails();
   } else {
      // display and/or log error messages here, then:
      return of(false);
   }
}

setUserPersonalDetails(): Observable <boolean> {
   // is ngxLoader an asynchronous function? 
   // if yes, make it the start of the observable chain, and switchMap()
   this.ngxLoader.start(); 

   return this.userService.getUserByUsername(this.username.toLowerCase().trim())
      .pipe(
         tap( /* do side effects here */ ),
         map( /* check if result satisfies conditions, return true or false accordingly */ )
      );
};
```

The consumer of `canEnterStep2` also has to treat it as an async stream.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work... canEnterStep2 has to be a boolean